# Website no longer works once domain is added

Tags: domains, github-pages

I have a website hosted on GitHub Pages.

When I first attached a custom domain from GoDaddy, the website served and worked perfectly across devices.

However, over time, the website stopped serving. At first, the website would not serve over Wifi, but would on cellular data, but then two weeks later it stopped serving on cellular data too with error "Too many redirects."

I tried adding Cloudlfare protection-- https://blog.cloudflare.com/secure-and-fast-github-pages-with-cloudflare/ , to check if the issue was bot traffic, but this didn't do anything either.The domain in question is portfolioperch.com

GoDaddy support says that it worked for them, and that it is a ISP issue.

Comment: What are your DNS settings for the domain name?  What is your configuration within github pages (maybe provide a screen shot)?   Are you expecting `https` to work?  how about `www` and `no-www`?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller  I have everything removed right now so that the site could work with default GitHub pages domain, but these are the instructions I followed-- https://docs.github.com/en/pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site/managing-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site. I expected https to work, and it did from cellular data. I wasn't expecting www/no-www to work .

Comment: I don't think you have given enough info here for anybody to help you.  I'm a FIRST mentor and I'm happy to help FTC teams build websites.  Click on my profile and contact me though my website and we can set up a time to troubleshoot your problem.